# Labels on R barplot giving overall mean rather than individual mean

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I'm making barplot with an error bar for two categories. I want the bar to show the mean for each category and it keeps outputting the total mean on each bar so they are the same rather than different.

Here is my data:

```
Mean            sd                Top90%
27.49899    2.078367    90th Percentile
26.88160    2.140400    Remainder
```

I previously tried calculating the mean and sd in the dataframe with all my other data and was getting this same issue, so i created the new df with just the summary info

```
ggplot(data = bmiplot2, aes(x=`Top90%`, y=Mean)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour='grey', fill = "grey", width = .5) +
  ylab("mean BMI") + xlab(" ")+
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean(bmiplot2$Mean), 1)), size = 5, 
            position = position_dodge(0.85), vjust = -0.5, color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-sd, ymax=Mean+sd), width=.1,position=position_dodge(.9), color = "darkblue")
```

[image: plot visual]

Comment: Dont use the `$` operator in setting aesthetics. Does `round(Mean, 1))` work? (in `geom_text`, I mean)

Comment: Thank you! it's fixed now - I changed the round to (label = round(Mean, 1))